# HOW TO SAVE AND CONTINUE IN DJANGO LIKE IN DJANGO-ADMIN

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have a Django form below, I want to save a form by using two buttons: "Save & Add" and "Save & Continue" like in Django Admin.

```
<form method = 'POST' enctype = 'multipart/form-data'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {form | crispy}
    
    <div class="form-group">
          <button type="submit" name="save_add" class="btn btn-de-primary btn-sm text-light px-4 mt-3 mb-0">Save & Add</button> 
          <button type="submit" name="save_continue" class="btn btn-de-danger btn-sm text-light px-4 mt-3 mx-4 mb-0">Save & Continue</button> 
          <a href="{% url 'doctor:list_doctor' %}" class="btn btn-de-success btn-sm text-light px-4 mt-3 mb-0" type="button">Close</a> 
    </div>

</form>
```

My code in views.py is as follows:

```
def addDoctor(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DoctorForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form=form.save(commit=False)
            form.save()
            if request.POST.get('save_add'):
                
                messages.success(request,'Doctor is successfully added')
                return redirect('doctor:list_doctor') 
            
            elif request.POST.get('save_continue'):
               
                return redirect('doctor:add_doctor')
            
            return redirect('doctor:list_doctor')  

                        
    else:
        form = DoctorForm()
    context = {
        'form':form
    }
    
    return render(request,'doctor/add_doctor.html',context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRY THIS

```
if request.POST:
        if 'save_add' in request.POST:
             messages.success(request,'Doctor is successfully added')
             return redirect('doctor:list_doctor') 
        elif 'save_continue' in request.POST:
             return redirect('doctor:add_doctor')
```

Comment: It works. I don't know how but it works